# Restrict IE from asking save dialogue pop up and it should save automatically in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

[Have added image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61U0m.png)Am automating a functionality where on button click the IE download the file with a dialogue box pop with save /open and cancel instead i want to download the file automatically to a specific location in selenium C#. as am not much interested in automating the save dialogue box part.. I get fix for Mozilla and chrome no such options for IE. any links or ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reconsidering your approach as file download functionality is not something you should cover with tests as it is rather testing of IE browser than your application.

From the other hand if you need the information from the file or want to check its integrity there is an alternative way of downloading it.

1. Obtain its [`href` or `download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) or [`src`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) attribute via [IWebElement.GetAttribute()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) function - this way you will obtain the link to your .csv file
2. Use [HttpClient](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/02/17/httpclient-downloading-to-a-local-file/) to download the file and store it to the desired location

If your site assumes authentication you can [get the relevant Cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) from the browser via [driver.Manage().Cookies](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IOptions_Cookies.htm) property and add the relevant [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header to the HttpClient containing the cookies from the real browser session.

Comment: Thanks ,There are no changes happenign in my href to capture as it just gets downloaded , my html looks like so .. <a onclick="return ShowExportWarning();" id="btnExport" class="black-button pcb" href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnExport','')"><span>Export</span></a>